# Strength of the inequalities between the means, comparing $Q_n-A_n, A_n-G_n, G_n-H_n$.

Tags: inequality

For $n$ real positive numbers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$, let $$Q_n = \sqrt{\frac {\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k^2}n},$$ $$A_n = \frac {\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k}n,$$ $$G_n = (\prod_{k = 1}^n a_k)^{\frac 1n},$$ $$H_n = \frac n{\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac 1{a_k}}.$$

We have $$H_n \le G_n \le A_n \le Q_n.$$

My question is: how strong are these inequalities? Which are stronger and which are weaker?

By studying a special case I found that when $n = 2$, if $a_1 \not = a_2$, $$G_2 - H_2 \lt Q_2 - A_2 \lt A_2 - G_2,$$ but I don't know how to generalize this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the three inequalities $\,G_2-H_2\leq Q_2-A_2$, $\,Q_2-A_2\leq A_2-G_2$, $\,G_2-H_2\leq A_2-G_2\,$ generalizes to arbitrary $n$. For $n=4$ and $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=(1,2,3,10)$ we get
\begin{equation*}
(G_4-H_4,\,Q_4-A_4,\,A_4-G_4) \,\doteq\,(0.714,\,1.339,\,1.217)~,
\end{equation*}
and for $n=4$ and $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=(1,8,9,10)$ we get
\begin{equation*}
(G_4-H_4,\,Q_4-A_4,\,A_4-G_4) \,\doteq\,(2.186,\,0.842,\,1.820)~.
\end{equation*}
Perhaps there are counter-examples with $n=3\,$; I did not look out for them.

**[Later.]** $~$I was curious, so I did go looking out for counter-examples with $n=3$ and actually found them. For $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(7,8,10)$ we get
\begin{equation*}
(G_3-H_3,\,Q_3-A_3,\,A_3-G_3) \,\doteq\,(0.0872,\,0.0928,\,0.0908)~,
\end{equation*}
and for $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(1,3,4)$ we get
\begin{equation*}
(G_3-H_3,\,Q_3-A_3,\,A_3-G_3) \,\doteq\,(0.395,\,0.277,\,0.377)~.
\end{equation*}